# How to sort/count same records in List base on multiple properties

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

Classes:

```
public class Class1 {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Details details { get; set; }
}


public class Details {
    public string DetailsId { get; set; }
}

var class1List= new List<Class1>();
//lets say I have multiple records
//records(1, Details(1))
//records(1, Details(1))
//records(2, Details(2))
//records(1, Details(2))
//records(1, Details(1))
//records(3, Details(1))
```

Now I want to sort that `list` by Class1 `Id`, then out a count of how many same DetailsId with the result of:

```
[
//Id '1', DetailsId '1'
Id: 1 { 
Details(1),
Details(1),
Details(1)
} (Count: 3) | Same DetailsId

//Id '1', DetailsId '2'
Id: 1 {
Details(2)
} (Count: 1)

//Id '2', DetailsId '2'
Id: 2 {
Details(2)
} (Count: 1)

//Id '3', DetailsId '1'
Id: 3 {
Details(1)
} (Count: 1)
]
```

The output I want is like this:

1, 1, count = 3
1, 2, count = 1
2, 1, count = 1
3, 1, count = 1

How can I achieve this ? using `Dictionary` and how?

Comment: Isn't better if you change the `public Details details { get; set; }` in the `Class1` to `public List<Details> details = new List<Details>();`? Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, By making the key

> Tuple

or combination of Class1 Id, and Details ID

```
var Dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var item in records) {
            var tValue = new Tuple<string, string>(item.Id, item.details.DetailsId).ToString();
            if (!Dictionary1 .ContainsKey(tValue)) {
                Dictionary1 .Add(tValue, 1);
            } else {
                Dictionary1 .TryGetValue(tValue, out int count);
                Dictionary1 .Remove(tValue);
                Dictionary1 .Add(tValue, count + 1);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the LINQ `group by`. For the below code to work, you might need to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of `Class1` and `Details` classes.

```
var result = from record in records
             group record by record into groupCounts
             orderby record.Id
             select groupCounts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for *Linq* `GroupBy`?

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  var class1List = ...

  var result = class1List
    .GroupBy(item => new {      // we group by Id, details?.Id combination
       id1 = item.Id,
       id2 = item.details?.Id,   
     })
    .Select(group => new {      // and count items in each group
       id1 = group.Key.id1, 
       id2 = group.Key.id2,  
       count = group.Count()
     }) 
    .OrderBy(item => item.id1) // Not necessary, but let's represent counts
    .ThenBy(item => item.id2); // in some order
```

Let's have a look:

```
 string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
   .Select(item => $"{item.id1}, {item.id2}, count = {item.count}"));  

 Console.Write(report);
```

If you want, you can *materialize* `result` as a `Dictionary`:

```
 Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int> counts = result
   .ToDictionary(item => Tuple.Create(item.id1, item.id1),
                 item => item.count);
```

Answer (score 0):

`GroupBy` is the way to go. My proposal is to first project `Class1` objects into simple anonymous object which You can the use for grouping.

```
    var result = class1List
    .Select(c => new {C1_Id = c.Id, D_Id = c.details.DetailsId})
    .GroupBy(obj => obj)
```

After that You should just count, how many elements there are in each group:

```
.Select(gr => new {gr.Key, Count = gr.Count()});
```

For completeness, below is full code, printing the result in the same form You asked for:

```
void Main()
{
    var class1List = new List<Class1>
    {
        new Class1 { Id = "1", details = new Details { DetailsId = "1" } },
        new Class1 { Id = "1", details = new Details { DetailsId = "1" } },
        new Class1 { Id = "2", details = new Details { DetailsId = "2" } },
        new Class1 { Id = "1", details = new Details { DetailsId = "2" } },
        new Class1 { Id = "1", details = new Details { DetailsId = "1" } },
        new Class1 { Id = "3", details = new Details { DetailsId = "1" } }
    };

    var result = class1List
        .Select(c => new {C1_Id = c.Id, D_Id = c.details.DetailsId})
        .GroupBy(obj => obj)
        .Select(gr => new {gr.Key, Count = gr.Count()});

    foreach (var r in result)
        Console.WriteLine($"{r.Key.C1_Id}, {r.Key.D_Id}, count={r.Count}");     
}
```